# Setting orientation of Android Emulator - Pixel 5 - API 33

Tags: android, android-emulator, maui

I use the **Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)** Emulator to run and test my .NET MAUI Application for Android.

On iOS-Simulator there is a button to switch the orientation of the App as if I would really turn my mobile phone from Portrait to Landscape view.

In the obove Androit-Emulator I can only Buttons called "Rotate left" and "Rotate right", but they do not switch the Orientation but the entire Emulator which is kind of funny since it shows the exact same view only rotated.

For a test of the real world and for a test on a real device, I would expect that the actual content of the App should be switched and I can see how my app behaves when doing it.

Is there a way to do this? Or how do you test this?

Comment: By default, Android LOCKS orientation. search [android unlock orienttion](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+unlock+orientation). (Unlock via swipe down to Quick Settings, or via Settings / Display.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the android emulator's Auto-rotate function's default state is off. You needs to turn it on manually.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - that was exactely it :)
Unfortunately, since activating and trying to rotate the emulator is instable - But that is probably a different problem

Comment: An additional question would be "how" to turn on auto-rotate (or rather, how to open the settings on the emulator)?  I understand that this is done by swiping from the top of the screen, but all this does is move the emulator window.  Long press on the app does nothing, and long press on the home screen doesn't pull up the option to turn autorotate on.  Maybe a silly question, but it comes from an iOS user with lots of iOS development experience who is trying to explore Android Development.

Comment: There is no setting page for the auto-rotate on the android. It just seems like a shortcut.@JonH

Comment: I finally worked it out... clicking on the settings icon in the status bar within the Android Emulator doesn't work as the settings panel appears and then immediately disappears again.  Even this doesn't happen if your PC is slow, or just busy. I presume it all happens before the emulator/screen catches up.  DOUBLE clicking it opens the settings panel, and the rotation lock option is then accessible.